# Insecure form call in Wordpress Site (search box)

Tags: wordpress, https

I'm converting over to https, and every page that has the built-in WP search box causes the page to be flagged insecure. For example, this page:
https://selfreliantschool.com/treat-candida/
gives the error on line 337 (found using whynopadlock.com).

Line 337 is:

```
<form class="search-form" itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction" method="get" action="https://selfreliantschool.com/" role="search"><meta itemprop="target" content="https://selfreliantschool.com/?s={s}"/>
```

The only non-secure thing is itemtype, which shouldn't make a difference.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the `itemType` attribute in the template to `https://schema.org/SearchAction`.  That site seems to support HTTPS as well.

Comment: I didn't think itemType would affect the indicator, but apparently it does. Reloading the Genesis framework updated all the itemType attributes.